# Play framework 2.3.x subproject Global.java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a play 2.3.10 app with several strcuture:

```
├── app
│   └── Global.java
├── build.sbt
├── conf
│   ├── application.conf
│   ├── messages
│   ├── play.plugins
│   ├── routes
├── modules
│   ├── common
│   ├── frontend
│   ├── backend
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── Common.scala
│   ├── plugins.sbt
```

And inside **modules/frontend/app/** I have **FrontendGlobal.java**. Now I run "**activator**" in the base project folder, and then "**project frontend**" and finally "**run**"

The play application for that sub-project is started, but NO Global file is executed. I thought the root Global.java will be executed, but adding a trace in @onStart does not print anything. Even changing the file FrontendGlobal.java (in modules/frontend/app) to Global.java does not do any effect.

What is wrong here?

Just as additional information, my `build.sbt` from the base project contains:

```
lazy val common = project.in(file("modules/common")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava)
lazy val frontend = project.in(file("modules/frontend")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava).dependsOn(common)
lazy val backend = project.in(file("modules/backend")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava).dependsOn(common)
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava).dependsOn(common, frontend, backend).aggregate(common, frontend, backend)
```

**UPDATED**: Just my fault, in the frontend-application.conf I had `application.global=globals.FrontendGlobal`

Comment: Answer to your question and mark it as resolved to avoid people clicking whereas your problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every project should contain only one `Global.java` (as they can only have one `application.conf` and `routes`. The subprojects could have a `Subproject-Global.java` and you can reference it from the project application.conf (`subproject-application.conf`) as follows:

```
application.global=Subproject-Global
```